# Save a list of objects on exit of pygame game

Tags: python, persistence, pygame

So I have a list of defined classes that gets exported on the exit of the program.. and it looks like this:

```
<__main__.Block object at 0x02416B70>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x02416FF0>,
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C070>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C0D0>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C130>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C190>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x02416DF0>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C250>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C2B0>,
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C310>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C370>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C3D0>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C430>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C490>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C4F0>, 
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C550>,
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C5B0>,
<__main__.Block object at 0x0241C610>
```

Perfect! Right? Now I should easily be able to convert that to a list..
So I use this:

```
x=x.split(",")
```

And it converts it to a list yes, but it turns the classes into strings! Making them un-usable.

Basically what I need is to "suspend" the state of the game within a file when it is closed, and then reload it upon opening it.

So how can I do this without converting the class names to strings?

Comment: You can't call `split` on something that isn't already a string. Splitting doesn't convert it into a string. You'll have to show how you are creating that list.

Comment: Questions must _demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved_. You fail to understand that the data you have there already is a string - otherwise using `split` wouldn't work. Whatever you do to "export" your objects just results in their basic string representation being printed.

Comment: @dornhege *Is this a troll question?* What makes you think of that? Just because someone does not know everything does not make him a troll.

Comment: A troll would actually know the problem solution already. "Perfect! Right? ..." seems somewhat odd. Doesn't mean this is one.

Comment: I don't see why this question would deserve so many downvotes. Just because OP has made a wrong assumption? It's also pretty clear what he wants to do (serialize and deserialize some objects), how he tried it (writing strings to a textfile), and what is wrong about it (he's just writing the string representations to the file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Perfect! Right?

Sadly, no. What you see here (`<__main__.Block object at 0x02416B70>`) is a typical string representation of a class instance. It's just a simple string, and there's no way to convert this string back to an instance of of `Block`.

I assume you're still on this game from your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966882/how-to-do-collision-detection-in-a-plattformer-in-pygame).

So how do you actually persist the state of the game? The easiest way is to use the standard python module [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html).

In the following example, I'll use `shelve`, because you don't use a single class to represent the game state:

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object. ... the values ... in a shelf can be essentially arbitrary Python objects ... This includes most class instances, recursive data types, and objects containing lots of shared sub-objects. The keys are ordinary strings.

First of all, when we exit the game, we want to save the player and the blocks, so let's call a new `save` function when the game is about to exit:

```
while True:
    ...
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            save(player, blocklist)
            exit()
```

The implementation is quite easy (no error handling for brevity):

```
def save(player, blocks):
    f = shelve.open("save.bin") 
    f['player'] = player
    f['blocks'] = blocks
    f.close()
```

As you see, using `shelve` is as easy as using a `dict`.

Next step is loading our saved data.

```
player, blocklist = load() or (None, [])
```

We call a new function `load` which will either return a tuple of the saved player object and a list of the saved block objects, or `None`. In case of `None`, we don't create a player yet and use an empty list for our blocks.

The implementation is as simple as the `save` functon:

```
def load():
    try:
        f = shelve.open("save.bin") 
        return f['player'], f['blocks']
    except KeyError:
        return None
    finally:
        f.close()
```

And that's it.

Here's the complete code:

```
import pygame,random
from pygame.locals import *
from collections import namedtuple
import shelve

pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

max_gravity = 100

class Block(object):
    sprite = pygame.image.load("dirt.png").convert_alpha()
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(centery=y, centerx=x)

class Player(object):
    sprite = pygame.image.load("dirt.png").convert()
    sprite.fill((0,255,0))
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(centery=y, centerx=x)
        # indicates that we are standing on the ground
        # and thus are "allowed" to jump
        self.on_ground = True
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.jump_speed = 10
        self.move_speed = 8

    def update(self, move, blocks):

        # check if we can jump 
        if move.up and self.on_ground: 
            self.yvel -= self.jump_speed

        # simple left/right movement
        if move.left: self.xvel = -self.move_speed
        if move.right: self.xvel = self.move_speed

        # if in the air, fall down
        if not self.on_ground:
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # but not too fast
            if self.yvel > max_gravity: self.yvel = max_gravity

        # if no left/right movement, x speed is 0, of course
        if not (move.left or move.right):
            self.xvel = 0

        # move horizontal, and check for horizontal collisions
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, blocks)

        # move vertically, and check for vertical collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        self.on_ground = False;
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, blocks)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, blocks):
        # all blocks that we collide with
        for block in [blocks[i] for i in self.rect.collidelistall(blocks)]:

            # if xvel is > 0, we know our right side bumped 
            # into the left side of a block etc.
            if xvel > 0: self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            if xvel < 0: self.rect.left = block.rect.right

            # if yvel > 0, we are falling, so if a collision happpens 
            # we know we hit the ground (remember, we seperated checking for
            # horizontal and vertical collision, so if yvel != 0, xvel is 0)
            if yvel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                self.on_ground = True
                self.yvel = 0
            # if yvel < 0 and a collision occurs, we bumped our head
            # on a block above us
            if yvel < 0: self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

colliding = False
Move = namedtuple('Move', ['up', 'left', 'right'])

def load():
    try:
        f = shelve.open("save.bin") 
        return f['player'], f['blocks']
    except KeyError:
        return None
    finally:
        f.close()

def save(player, blocks):
    f = shelve.open("save.bin") 
    f['player'] = player
    f['blocks'] = blocks
    f.close()

player, blocklist = load() or (None, [])

while True:
    screen.fill((25,30,90))
    mse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            save(player, blocklist)
            exit()

        if key[K_LSHIFT]:
            if event.type==MOUSEMOTION:
                if not any(block.rect.collidepoint(mse) for block in blocklist):
                    x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                    y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                    blocklist.append(Block(x+16,y+16))
        else:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if event.button == 1:
                    to_remove = [b for b in blocklist if b.rect.collidepoint(mse)]
                    for b in to_remove:
                        blocklist.remove(b)

                    if not to_remove:
                        x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                        y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                        blocklist.append(Block(x+16,y+16))

                elif event.button == 3:
                    x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                    y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                    player=Player(x+16,y+16)

    move = Move(key[K_UP], key[K_LEFT], key[K_RIGHT])

    for b in blocklist:
        screen.blit(b.sprite, b.rect)

    if player:
        player.update(move, blocklist)
        screen.blit(player.sprite, player.rect)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

And here you can see loading and saving in action:

[image]

Note that you can't save (or "pickle") `Surfaces` this way. In this code, it works because the `Surfaces` of `Player` and `Block` are class variables, not instance variables, and thus don't get saved to disk. If you want to "pickle" an object with a `Surface` instance variable, you would have to remove the `Surface` first (e.g. setting it to `None`) and load it again (e.g. in the `load` function).

Comment: What are you using to make those nice gifs?

Comment: @monkey GifRecorder from gifrecorder.com if i'm on my Windows machine